# Google tag assistant reports: “Same web property ID is tracked twice”when trying to install google analytics code

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I was trying to install google analytics code into our google tag manager at first I installed the GTM and add a tag that I grabbed from tracking ID and after all that, it doesn't seem to appear an analytical dashboard on my account.

I was wondering how do I fix this error on Google tag assistant and also to have the dashboard appear. thank you so much.

page script

script below

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-171638252-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-171638252-1');
</script>
```

Errors shown as below image,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This double-tracked ID's behaviour could be caused if you have loaded your tracking code both inline on the website, and through GTM as well. Please make sure that you do not load your tracking both inline on the website, and through GTM. This is my initial guess so far, unfortunately, I could not give you a final solution to this issue without seeing the source code and domain.